# How to get a tag in html with queryselectorall provided with a condition in VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, queryselector

Snippet:

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="left">
<nobr>FILENAME</nobr>
</td>
<td valign="center" align="left">
<b>
<font size="2px">
<nobr>FILENUMBER0311</nobr>
</font>
</b>
<font size="2px">&nbsp;</font>
</td>
<td valign="top" align="right"></td>
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="left">Date</td>
<td colspan="2" valign="center" align="left">
<font color="#C00000">
<b>
CANCELED
</b>
</tr>

…

<tr>
<td valign="top" align="left">
<nobr>FILENAME</nobr>
</td>
<td valign="center" align="left">
<b>
<font size="2px">
<nobr>FILENUMBER0345</nobr>
</font>
</b>
<font size="2px">&nbsp;</font>
</td>
<td valign="top" align="right"></td>
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="left">Date</td>
<td colspan="2" valign="center" align="left">
<font color="#C00000">
<b>
CONFIRMED
</b>
</tr>
```

The website-html has a table with several tr-tags. In each tr-tag there is either the entry CONFIRMED between b-tags or the entry CANCELED. I need a code that returns the value of FILENUMBERxxxx in the case of CONFIRMED. I have no idea how to combine a "selector", "instr" and possible other operations with each other in this case.

My Code: (nothing happens!). Does anyone know a solution? THX

```
    Sub GetData()
    
Const url = "https://www.zvg-portal.de/index.php?button=Suchen&all=1"
    Dim Html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim xhr As Object, elm As Object
    Dim I As Long
            
    Set Html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
        
    With xhr
        .Open "POST", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send "ger_name=--" & " " & "Alle" & " " & "Amtsgerichte" & " " & "--&" & "order_by=2&land_abk=ni&ger_id=0"
         Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

With Html.querySelectorAll("tr")
Set elm = Html.querySelectorAll("tr")
    For I = 0 To 500
    'right now I do not know how to set the number of repeats, therefore 0 to 500
        If InStr(elm.Item(I).innerText, "Termin") > 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(I + 2, 3) = elm.Item(I).ParentNode.PreviousSibling.FirstChild.NextSibling.innerText
            'need the numeric value of Aktenzeichen
            Exit For
        End If
    Next I

End With
        
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share the site url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following processes the rows and when it sees a listing separator (`tr` with only 1 child `td`), it increments the row counter for the output array.

It uses an `Instr` test, for `aufgehoben`, to determine if the row with `termin` indicates a cancellation and returns a True/False value in the output array.

During the loop, the `Aktenzeichen` value is extracted; this is written out in the first column of the output array, before the True/False for cancelled.

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetData()
    Const url = "https://www.zvg-portal.de/index.php?button=Suchen&all=1"
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, xhr As Object
     
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        
    With xhr
        .Open "POST", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send "ger_name=--" & " " & "Alle" & " " & "Amtsgerichte" & " " & "--&" & "order_by=2&land_abk=ni&ger_id=0"
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable
    
    Set table = html.querySelector("table[border='0']")
    
    Dim row As MSHTML.HTMLTableRow, newBlock As Boolean
    Dim r As Long, cancellations(), aktenzeichen As String
    
    ReDim cancellations(1 To 1000, 1 To 2)
    
    r = 1
    
    For Each row In table.Rows
        
        If newBlock Then r = r + 1
        
        If InStr(1, row.innerHTML, "Aktenzeichen", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            aktenzeichen = Replace$(row.Children(1).getElementsByTagName("nobr")(0).innerText, " (Detailansicht)", vbNullString)
            cancellations(r, 1) = aktenzeichen
        End If
        
        If Trim$(row.Children(0).innerText) = "Termin" Then
            cancellations(r, 2) = (InStr(1, row.Children(1).innerText, "aufgehoben", vbTextCompare) > 0)
        End If

        newBlock = (row.Children.Length = 1)
        
    Next
    
    cancellations = Application.Transpose(cancellations)
    
    Dim headers()
    
    headers = Array(" Aktenzeichen", "Cancelled")
    ReDim Preserve cancellations(1 To UBound(headers) + 1, 1 To r)
    
    cancellations = Application.Transpose(cancellations)
    
    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(cancellations, 1), UBound(cancellations, 2)) = cancellations
    End With

End Sub
```